# Problema de asincronia en una peticion ajax. Funcion 2 se ejecuta antes que la funcion 1

Tags: jquery, ajax

estoy haciendo un ajax que carga un combobox, cuando cargue el combobx tengo una funcion en js llamada `esAdmin()` que mira cual es el valor de combobox pero aun sale vacio aun estando el ajax antes que la comprobacion, lo he probado con el evento `done` y otros mas pero nada.

El tema es que es asincrono. La funcion `esAdmin()` se carga en dos momentos:

1. Al terminar el ajax que se ejecuta al carga la pagina.
2. Al cambiar de valor el combobox.

Pero en ningun caso me muestra que haya datos en el combobox. 
Añadir que la carga de datos de los roles mediante la peticion ajax lo hace bien, es decir, el combobox se carga correctamente.

A continuacion dejo el codigo:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Añadir Rol</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{URL::to('addRol')}}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('POST')

                        <div class="form-group row" style="text-align:center;">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h2>Hola <b>{{Auth::user()->name}}</b>, parece que aun no tienes un rol asignado. <b>Selecciona un Rol</b> antes de empezar a navegar por la aplicacion</h2>     
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">        
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="rol" id="comboboxRol" onchange="esAdmin();">
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row" id="div_admin"> 
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label class="form-check-label text-danger mx-4" ><b>Para tener rol de Administrador debes de proporcionar un codigo secreto.</b></label>     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input_admin">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">        
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Guardar Rol</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('js')
    <script>



        var divAdmin =document.getElementById('div_admin');
        var comboBoxjs = document.getElementById('comboboxRol');

        $(document).ready(function(){
                //ajax que carga los roles
              var promesa =   $.ajax({
                    url        :'/ajax/getAllRol',
                    type       :'GET',
                    dataType   :'json',
                    success    :function(result){

                    var comboBoxjs = document.getElementById('comboboxRol');
                    // console.log(comboBoxjs.options);
                    result.forEach(element => {
                        var opt = document.createElement('option');
                        opt.value = element.id;
                        opt.innerHTML = element.nombre;
                        comboBoxjs.appendChild(opt);
                    });

                    }
        });
//cuando el ajax se haya completado
        $.when(promesa).done(function (params) {
            console.log('WHEN');
            console.log('params');
            console.log(params);
            if (params) {
                esAdmin();    
            }

        })


    });


        function esAdmin(){
            console.log('combobox cambiado');


            //console.log(comboBox);
            var rolSeleccionado ;
            console.log('ROL SELECCIONADO');
            console.log(comboBoxjs.options);
            //console.log(comboBoxjs.options);

        }

    </script>
@endsection
```